# Property e.propgatedFrom.feature not available in marker cluster click event in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, point, clustering, markers, properties

In a Leaflet map, when a point feature is clicked I want to capture its attributes and pass them onto some variables. The point feature is part of a cluster.
The leaflet marker cluster is sourced as below:

```
  <!--leaflet marker cluser-->
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

> 

Point feature and the cluster is defined as below:

```
var mcPri = L.markerClusterGroup();

var schoolP = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/schools.json', {pointToLayer:function(feature,latlng){
                var str = "<h6><b>"+feature.properties.sch_name+"<br>School</h6>";
                     return mcPri.addLayer(L.marker(latlng,{icon: schIcon}).bindPopup(str));
                                               
                }});
```

I am trying to capture attribute info when clicked as below:

```
var id, sch_name;
       schoolP.on('click', function(e) {  
            console.log(e);
            coord = e.latlng;
            latitude = e.latlng.lat;
            longitude = e.latlng.lng;
            id=e.propagatedFrom.feature.properties.id;
            sch_name=e.propagatedFrom.feature.properties.sch_name;
        })
```

There is no e.propagedFrom.feature in the console.log. Screenshot is below:
[image]

However, if the point feature is not part of a cluster, then it works fine.

```
var schoolP = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/schools.json', {pointToLayer:function(feature,latlng){
                var str = "<h6><b>"+feature.properties.sch_name+"<br>School</h6>";
                     return L.marker(latlng,{icon: schIcon}).bindPopup(str));


                                           
            }});
```

Screenshot without cluster is below:
[image]

How can I get the attributes of a point features which are part of a cluster?
I could not find similar questions in the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating markers and adding them to marker cluster with the `pointToLayer` option function of `L.GeoJSON.AJAX`, you are not returning created marker

```
return L.marker(latlng,{icon: schIcon}).bindPopup(str);
```

but clustered marker

```
return mcPri.addLayer(L.marker(latlng,{icon: schIcon}).bindPopup(str));
```

This interferes with the process of assigning feature property to the original nonclustered marker.

One possible solution for this is to return original marker in the `pointToLayer` option function. Code could then look like this:

```
var schoolP = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/schools.json', {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var str = "<h6><b>" + feature.properties.sch_name + "<br>School</h6>";
    var marker = L.marker(latlng,{icon: schIcon}).bindPopup(str);
    mcPri.addLayer(marker);
    return marker;
  }
});
```

Personally I would rather do it with `onEachFeature` option function:

```
var schoolP = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/schools.json', {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var str = "<h6><b>" + feature.properties.sch_name + "<br>School</h6>";
    layer.bindPopup(str);
    layer.setIcon(schIcon);
    mcPri.addLayer(layer);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected but the cluster is behaving bit odd. It does not cluster the marker when zoom in and out like earlier. Anyway, I am accepting the answer because it solves the original issue of not being able to retrieve attributes of markers in a clusterGroup. It is now possible. I will look into cluster option in bit detail to make it work as before.

Comment: It works OK for me, so there must be something wrong with your code. See working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/nr45yqvg/

Comment: Your code is similar to mine but somehow clustering is behaving odd: 1) it does not cluster like before (leaves some markers un-clustered even at zoom level 6). 2) when I turn off the layer from layer control, it turns it off, but as soon as I zoom in/out, the cluster and the marker start re-appearing even when the layer is still turned off in the layer control. So it is bit odd. I will re-check the whole code and see what is causing the issue, it might be the same issue that I posted in another question where the markers get loaded even when I comment out: //schoolP.addTo(mymap);

Comment: I found the issue. Leaflet control search was making look like clustering is not working as expected. When it is disabled clustering as well as e.propgatedFrom.feature all working fine.